# Prerender.io not loaded scripts correctly

Tags: angularjs, google-crawlers, prerender

I have two javascript files:

> vendor.js - where I have angular.js and another libs;
>   app.js - own code.

But when I loaded it prerender not opened my page.

When I concatenate it to one file - all OK.

How can I fix it?

Comment: [Tell us exactly when your pages are ready to be saved.](https://prerender.io/documentation/best-practices) - Read that paragraph

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might be loading those `<script>` tags in the `<body>` of your page. Scripts that are in the body are loaded asynchronously so they can load out of order (and cause javascript errors if loaded out of order). Chrome and most browsers handle this nicely but PhantomJS can load them out of order.

I'd suggest trying to move those `<script>` tags into the `<head>` and see if that fixes your issue.